# Stack Exchange API Types - a type declaration package for API types

Tags: library, typescript

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: animated example]

Usage example:

```
import {
    CommonWrapperObject,
    Errors,
    Filters,
    Tag,
} from "@userscripters/stackexchange-api-types";

export const getTagsAPI = async (search: string): Promise<Tag[]> => {
    const filter: Filters.BuiltIn = "default";

    const uri = new URL(`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/tags`);
    uri.search = new URLSearchParams({
        site: location.hostname,
        inname: search.toLowerCase(),
        filter,
    }).toString();

    const res = await fetch(uri.toString());
    if (!res.ok) return [];

    const body = await res.json();

    const { items, error_name } = body as CommonWrapperObject<Tag>;

    const errorMap: Map<Errors.Name, string> = new Map([
        ["bad_parameter", "Invalid parameter"],
        ["access_denied", "The API refused access"],
    ]);

    console.log(errorMap.get(error_name));

    return items;
};
```

### About

Stack Exchange API types is a type declaration package adding type definitions for objects exposed by Stack Exchange API for both client- and server-side consumption.

The package is automatically generated, so all currently available types should be present in the definitions - do let us know if we missed anything!

#### License

The package is licensed under the [GPL-3.0-or-later](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later) license.

#### Download

The package is published as both an [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@userscripters/stackexchange-api-types) and a [GitHub package](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-api-types/packages/996732). Can be installed via a package manager like NPM as usual:

```
npm install --save-dev @userscripters/stackexchange-api-types
```

If you opt to install it from the GitHub registry, please note that it only supports scoped packages, you will need a simple .npmrc file at your project root:

```
@userscripters:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

You will also need to be logged in to GitHub. An easy way to do so is to have a global `.npmrc` with your PAT ([personal access token](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later)) set as an access token:

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=<your token here>
```

#### Platform

The type declarations are intended to be used with TypeScript/JavaScript projects targeting either browsers or server-side environments like Node.js.

### Changelog

| Version | Changes |
| --- | --- |
| [0.3.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-api-types/packages/996732?version=0.3.0) | Deduplicated generated interfaces & exported types globally as `StackExchangeAPI` namespace |
| [1.0.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-api-types/packages/996732?version=1.0.0) | Fixed type `date` from the API being incorrectly interpreted as `Date` (it is a `number`) |
| [2.0.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-api-types/packages/996732?version=2.0.0) | ["may be absent"](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/absent-fields) fields are now considered optional interface members. This makes the types more accurate but might be a breaking change for your codebase |
| [3.1.1](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-api-types/packages/996732?version=3.1.1) | [Common Wrapper Object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper) that the API sends the responses wrapped into is added to the list of generated types. The interface accepts a generic type parameter for the `items` array values |
| [3.2.4](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-api-types/packages/996732?version=3.2.4) | [Built-in filters](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) (e.g. `default` or `total`) string union grouped under `Filters` namespace |
| [3.3.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-api-types/packages/996732?version=3.3.0) | [API errors](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/error-handling) as `Name` and `Code` unions grouped under `Errors` namespace |
| [3.4.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-api-types/packages/996732?version=3.4.0) | API error types are propagated to the common wrapper object fields `error_name` and `error_id` |

### Contact

Author: [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter)
Organization: [UserScripters](https://github.com/userscripters)

Please, submit bug reports on the [source repository](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-api-types/issues).

Before adding a new one, please check if it hasn't been raised before.

You can also [drop by to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345/userscript-newbies-and-friends), we are a friendly bunch.

### Code

[Source code](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-api-types) is written TypeScript (`d.ts` declaration files and type generator in proper TypeScript).

The project is using `tsd` (see [repo](https://github.com/SamVerschueren/tsd)) for unit-testing types.

Contributions are welcome, you can always submit a [PR here](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-api-types/pulls).

Comment: Why is the Answer interface listed twice in the types.d.ts file?

Comment: @rene v0.2.0, that's why :) I was a bit too busy with setting up AST parsing -> pretty-printing, so I forgot that some of the definitions can duplicate the way SE sets things up - and since TS simply does declaration merging on interfaces, no errors popped up - should work fine as is, but I'll add a filter for the duplicate interfaces in the next version

Comment: @rene done, version 0.3.0 features interface deduplication :) Since the compiler API is incredibly poorly documented I am not sure if there is a way to dedupe them properly, but should be enough unless SE suddenly decides to use partial declarations. On an off-note, the types are now also exported as a global namespace to make them viable in non-module userscripts too.

Comment: Would it be OK if I use this package in my own? Giving you credit, of course

Comment: @MrMythical of course - it is nice to see the package is being used :) I think you already give enough attribution when jnstalling the package via the metadata provided by package.json, so I don't think there is anything that needs to be done at all - just use it, and if you find issues/have feature requests - just let me know